# What did i do wrong with "move" command in cmd (batch file/script)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

here's the code;

```
::set var output dir
SET outputdir= %~dp0output

::user define the file path
set /p decrypt= Enter File Path: 

::then we move the file from "%decrypt%" to "%ouputdir%"="/output"
move /Y %decrypt% %outputdir%
```

> Result; The syntax of the command is incorrect.

I don't know what i do/did wrong but i would like to know any fix to this ty <3

Comment: Do either `%decrypt%` or `%outputdir%` have spaces in them? If so, you need to put quotes around them.

Comment: Please read [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) There is at least `outputdir` defined wrong as there is a space right to the equal sign which must be removed to be able to reference the value of `outputdir` enclosing it in `"`. So correct would be `set "outputdir=%~dp0output\"` and `set /P "decrypt=Enter file path: "` and finally `move /Y "%decrypt:"=%" "%outputdir%"`.

Comment: Please note further that `::` is an invalid label and not really the correct syntax for a remark (comment) which are defined with command `rem` in a batch file. Run in a command prompt window `rem /?` for help on the remark command.

Answer (score 0):

```
move /Y "%decrypt%" "%outputdir%"
```

without knowing exactly what your response was to the two prompts, this would be a guess. If either of the directory names you entered contained eg. spaces then `cmd` will treat that name as multiple parameters. Quoting the names tells `cmd` that the name actually contains spaces.

Comment: *i tried removing the ' " ' characters but didnt do anything*
here's the only output i get;

Enter File Path: "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test\lol.png"
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
Press any key to continue . . .

if you have any socials that i can send you the full code of it you can send it to me here :)